# Question about the use of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a_1,...,a_n$ be positive numbers. By the use of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality I have to show that
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_k}\right) \geq n^2,\;\;\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N.}$$
Here is what I tried: let $u=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $v=(1/a_1,...,1/a_n)$ $\in \mathbb{R}^n$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we must have:
$${\langle u, v \rangle}^2 \leq \|{u}\|^2\|{v}\|^2$$
it becomes:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{a_1}{a_1}+\dotsb+\frac{a_n}{a_n}\right)^2 &\leq \left(a_1^2+\dotsb+a_n^2\right)\left(\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{a_n^2}\right)\\
\implies n^2 &\leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_k^2} \right)
\end{align}
This differs from the answer only because of the squared terms in the sums.
Did I do something wrong? Is the question wrong? Any tips would be great!

Comment: Try a slightly different $u, v$. Hint: What $u$ gives us $ \sum a_k$?

Comment: Hint: your $u$ and $v$ are close, but not quite what you want.

Comment: yeah, maybe i'm just tired. it will work if i use $u=(\sqrt{a_1},...,\sqrt{1/a_n})$ and the analogous for $v$. Thank you both for waking me up